# Libgdx - Black Screen mystery

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx, shader

I want to do a simple gradient using the Mesh class in libGDX. This is supposed to a draw rectangle containing the gradient, but the problem is that the rectangle is completely black !

**My code :**

```
public class HomeScreen extends
                        ScreenAdapter {

    OrthographicCamera  camera;
    Mesh                mesh;
    ShaderProgram       shader;

    public HomeScreen() {
        Logger.message("HomeScreen()", "^");
        this.camera = new OrthographicCamera(2, 2);
        this.mesh = new Mesh(false, 4, 4,
                                new VertexAttribute(Usage.Position, 3, ShaderProgram.POSITION_ATTRIBUTE),
                                new VertexAttribute(Usage.ColorPacked, 4, ShaderProgram.COLOR_ATTRIBUTE)
                );
        this.shader = SpriteBatch.createDefaultShader();

        this.camera.position.set(0, 0, 0);
        this.camera.update();
        this.mesh.setVertices(new float[] {
                -0.5f, -0.5f, 0, Color.BLUE.toFloatBits(),
                -0.5f, 0.5f, 0, Color.RED.toFloatBits(),
                0.5f, 0.5f, 0, Color.RED.toFloatBits(),
                0.5f, -0.5f, 0, Color.BLUE.toFloatBits(),
        });
        this.mesh.setIndices(new short[] {
                0, 1, 3, 2
        });
        Logger.message("HomeScreen()", "$");
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        Logger.message("HomeScreen.dipose()", "^");
        this.mesh.dispose();
        this.shader.dispose();
        Logger.message("HomeScreen.dipose()", "$");
    }

    @Override
    public void render(final float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        this.shader.begin();
        this.shader.setUniformMatrix("u_projTrans", this.camera.combined);
        this.mesh.render(this.shader, GL20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
        this.shader.end();
    }
}
```

**The result :**

http://snag.gy/oduhL.jpg

Any idea ?

Comment: Having a look at the default spritebatch shader, one can see that this shader requires a texture and calculates the final color as `gl_FragColor = v_color * texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);`. Since you did not supply a texture, you v_color will most probably be multiplied by a zero-vector.

Comment: @BDL I wrote my own shader without the texture part and indeed it worked. Thanks

Comment: @BDL Can you post this as answer so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default shader for SpriteBatches in libgdx requires textures to work. When looking at the [shader code](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.java), one will see, that the final result is a composition of the vertex color and the texture color:

```
gl_FragColor = v_color * texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);
```

When not supplying a texture, the vertex color will be multiplied by [0,0,0,0], which results in a black output.